# Compare two strings in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I need to take value from row from page

my code is

```
String bname1 = selenium.getText("//table[@id='bank']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]");
assertEquals(bname1,"HDFC");
if(bname1=="HDFC") {
    System.out.println("Bank name is:"+bname1);
} else {
    System.out.println("Bank name not found");
}
System.out.println(bname1);
```

Result:
Bank name not found
HDFC

My bank name is "VIJAYA"
But when i compare to "bname1" and "VIJAYA",RESULT will be negative?
How can i compaire these strings
pls help me...

Comment: You failed to mention that this was using JAVA.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot compare strings in Java using `==`.  All that does is test to see if the two objects have the same address in memory/are the same instance.  Use `.equals()` instead, like:

`if(bname1.equals("HDFC"))`

...or preferably:

`if("HDFC".equals(bname1))`

Which is better because it won't crash if 'bname1' is `null`.

Comment: Use PMD to pick up this kind of error! It's free and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code has some other issues as well. When you call assertEquals() that tells the compiler to check if the two values are equal and then stop executing code if the condition is not true. Because of this the print statements found after your assertEquals() statement will not get executed if the assertion fails. Instead you should try to do something like the following.

```
String bname1 = selenium.getText("//table[@id='bank']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]");
assertEquals("Bank name - "+bname1+" should be HDFC",bname1,"HDFC");
```

If you write your statement like this the first parameter of the assertEquals function will become the error message displayed when the assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("Url");

        WebElement strvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("  "));
        String expected = "Text to compare";
        String actual = strvalue.getText();
        System.out.println(actual);

    if(expected.equals(actual)){
        System.out.println("Pass");
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure It will help you

````
assertEquals(bname1,"HDFC");
if(bname1.equals("HDFC")) {
    System.out.println("Bank name is:"+bname1);
} else {
    System.out.println("Bank name not found");
}
System.out.println(bname1);```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use assertions like:

```
Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedString, ActualString);
```

Here ExpectedString is a string that is expected and ActualString is original String value.